# MahApps Metro set two different icons on title bar and on taskbar for a window

Tags: wpf, titlebar, mahapps.metro

I want to use 2 different images : 1 on title bar, second on taskbar .

If using ShowIconOnTitleBar property then it will use same "ICON" property to both .

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `IconTemplate` to set a different icon for the window title bar.

e.g.

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.IconTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
              Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
              Margin="4"
              Background="{DynamicResource IdealForegroundColorBrush}"
              RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"
              RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased">
            <Grid.OpacityMask>
                <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform" Visual="{DynamicResource appbar_box}" />
            </Grid.OpacityMask>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Controls:MetroWindow.IconTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks . I will try it, also i will need to change icon template in code behide as my icons depends by Solution Build Configurations...